# Qt: QPainter paintPixmap will be clipped to QSlider's widget's area

Tags: qt, qpainter

I have two ui-objects designed in the ui-builder. 
The first one is a custom QFrame class which overwrites the paintEvent method. This is the place where I want to draw pixmaps. In the vertical middle of the frame, there is a QSlider(second ui-object). The slider can be seen as a timeline for a media player. the frame has a height of 80px, the slider a height of 60px. From a file I read some special time points for every media files. At each timepoint I want to draw a pixmap above or below the slider. The pixmaps have a size of 10x34px.

The problem when I do this, that the drawn pixmaps are clipped around the slider area. I read the example customizing QSlider with stylesheets and discovered the two attibutes groove and handle. I tried different qss attributes like opacity or background-clip, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idee how to configure the painter that the drawn objects are onto the slider area of how to configure the stylesheet of the slider that it's area is translucent? Any proposal would be helpful!

Thx in advance
Andreas

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question to include a screenshot of the problem so it is more clear?

Comment: Ok I'm going to link my drop box directory. This is how the customer wants to see the timeline : [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsrwo2tu8f9lok2/customer_desire.png?dl=0) . The next screenshot shows the current state: [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5c5k5otno9wlj9/slider_with_clipped_marker.png?dl=0

Comment: Subclass `QSlider`, reimplement its `paintEvent`, in that implementation call base class implementation to draw default slider appearance and then draw additional decorations. Also if you don't care about complying with system theme, it may be reasonable to draw the slider manually.